# Inputenc errors with mathematical equations

Tags: errors, amsmath, packages

I am facing a lot of errors about package `inputenc`  when I use mathematical functions like `$` or `\begin{align}`. However, I identified in the package list all math packages including:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

And I still get errors from LaTeX messages

[image: Error messages]

here is my code that I have done

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
République Algérienne Démocratique et Populaire\\
\end{LARGE}
\begin{LARGE}
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieure et de la Recherche Scientifique.\\
 \bigskip 
 \bigskip
\end{LARGE}
\textsc{Ecole National Supérieure Travaux Publics Kouba}\\
\medskip
Cycle d'ingénieur - Deuxième Année.\\
Département des Matériaux et Structure.\\
\bigskip
\begin{Huge}
\underline{\textbf{Etude de projet routier}}\\
\end{Huge}
\bigskip
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width= 14cm , height= 7cm]{../../Documents/Carte Médéa.PNG}  
\end{center}
\bigskip
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{2pt}\\
\bigskip
\begin{LARGE}
\textbf{L'évitement de la Wilaya de Médéa}\\
\end{LARGE}
\bigskip
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
    \underline{\emph{Sous Groupe: 9}}\\
    \textsc{GASMI} Mohamed Wassim.\\
                \textsc{RAHMANI} Mahmoud.\\
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
    \underline{\emph{Responsable de Matière:}} \\
  \textsc{Mr.DERRADJI} \\
  \end{flushright}

\end{minipage}
 \vspace{1in}
\begin{center}
Gharidi, Kouba\\
2020/2021
\end{center}
\end{center}
\newpage
\vspace{2in}
\begin{center}
\huge{\textbf{Remerciement}} \\ [0.75cm]
\textit{Avant tout développement sur cette expérience professionnelle, il est tellement agréable de
commencer ce rapport par des remerciements, à ceux qui m’ont beaucoup appris au
cours de cette sortie, et même à ceux qui ont eu la gentillesse de faire un moment très profitable.}\\
\textit{Aussi, on remercie Mr.DERRADJI qui nous ont formés et accompagnés tout au long de cette expérience d'apprentissage avec beaucoup de patience et de pédagogie.}
\end{center}
\newpage
\section*{Introduction}
L'avant Projet sommaire est entrepris une fois sélectionnée les solutions retenues\\ de la phase 1 (étude préliminaire). Il a pour tache principale de préciser la solution la plus adaptée  à partir d'un plan topographique à l'échelle de 1/5000. Il s'agit de à partir du couloir retenu, de définir le tracé le plus approprié et le plus  économique et de préciser le cadre de dimensionnement(normes d'aménagement) applicable au projet\\
Quelques ripages d'axes pourront etre effectués ainsi que des modifications de ligne rouge (profil en long). Les études de drainage et d'assainissement sont également entreprises dans cette phase. 
\section*{Objectif}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Elaboration du tracé avec le choix définitif des caractéristiques géométriques.
\item Définir le tracé comme une succession d'alignement, de rayons et de raccordements à courbure progressive.
\item déterminer les valeurs des paramètres de dimension du projet, de façon à permettre l'estimation du coût du projet.
\end{enumerate}
\section*{Situation et définition du Projet:}
 Le tronçon routier va permettre de soulager l’agglomération du chef-lieu du flux de véhicules circulant dans les deux sens et qui encombraient la ville. La mise en service du contournement va, à coup sûr, mettre fin au goulot d’étranglement qui a toujours marqué le passage par le carrefour Est, en assurant une meilleure fluidité de la circulation du et vers le centre-ville. La nouvelle voie de contournement va mettre fin au problème de congestion à l’entrée de la ville, causée par les flux de véhicules de gros tonnage qui empruntent la RN1 et, ainsi, faire gagner beaucoup de temps aux usagers de ce tronçon.\\
      Les travaux de réalisation de l’évitement de la ville de Médéa s’inscrivent aussi dans le cadre du renforcement du programme de la réhabilitation du réseau routier mené depuis plusieurs années dans l’objectif d’arriver à une meilleure fluidification de la circulation et une meilleure régulation des véhicules empruntant les principales pénétrantes de la wilaya.le réseau routier existant a nécessité d’importants travaux de réfection et de traitement contre les dégradations causées par l’érosion et par la circulation de véhicules devenue de plus en plus importante du fait de l’augmentation du parc automobile.Le lancement d’un mégaprojet de l'évitement de la wilya de Médéa permettra, à terme, de faciliter la circulation des biens et des services, et donnera un plus grand essor aux échanges entre l'ouest et l'est de la ville.     
     \begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=3cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/TP/Départ-Arrivé.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Points de départ et arrivée}
    &
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/TP/Carte géographique.png} 
    \captionof{figure}{Carte géographique de Wilaya de Médéa}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\section*{Rappel sur les deux variantes retenues}
Selon l'étude préliminaire, on a retenue deux variantes optimales:
\subsection*{Variante 1 :}
La longueur totale la Variante 1 est de 7 Km, elle commence au rond point qui donne accés au quartier de DRAA ESSEMAR qui est considérée comme la porte du coté Est de la ville. Le tracé traverse ensuite des terres agricoles à 1.15 km qui est rectiligne puis il passe sur les montagnes de Ain Arayess pour arriver à la route de Tibhirine. La variante continuera son chemin à partir du nord est de la route de Tibhirine d'environ 1.37 km de longueur et contourner les montagnes et les habitations existantes pour arriver à l'ancienne autoroute du coté Nord ouest de la ville. L'alignement reproduit L'autoroute existante du coté Nord ouest et continue son chemin à 1.58 Km de longueur en traversant les terres agricoles. La variante coupe le rond point existant et continue son chemin en traversant les terres agricoles à 4.48 Km de longueur pour arriver au viaduc de l'autoroute Nord-Sud.
\begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=4cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/debut var1.png}  
\captionof{figure}{Point de départ}
    &
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/fin var 1.png}  
    \captionof{figure}{Point d'arrivée}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=8cm , width= 15cm]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/var 1.png} 
   \captionof{figure}{Variante 1}
        \end{center}    
        \subsection*{Variante 3}
        La longueur de la variante 3 est de 14.3 Km qui commence par la route Nationale Numéro 18, en traversant le oued, elle monte sur une terre agricole d'altitude 713 m puis elle traverse une route existante pour rentrer dans les terres d'altitude minimales sur une longueur de 9.17 m qui nous permettre de contourner la zone d'habitation et les propriétés privées et les terres agricoles. Sur cette longueur, elle traverse 2 routes de plus pour arriver à l'autoroute Nord-Sud.
        \begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=4cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/début var 3.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Point de départ}
    &
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/fin var 3.png} 
    \captionof{figure}{Point d'arrivée}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[height=7cm , width= 15cm]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/var 3.png} 
  \captionof{figure}{Variante 3} 
  \end{center} 
\section*{Un aperçu sur la norme à utiliser}
\subsection*{Etude de Trafic}
La capacité dépend de :
\begin{itemize}
\item  Des conditions de trafic.
\item  Des conditions météorologiques .
\item Le type d’usagers habitués ou non à l’itinéraire .
\item  Des distances de sécurité (ce qui intègre le temps de réaction des Conducteurs 
variables d’une route à l’autre) .
\item Des caractéristiques géométriques de la section considérée (nombre et largeur des 
voies). 
\subsubsection*{Calcul de TJMA}
La formule qui donne le trafic journalier moyen annuel à l’année horizon est : 
\end{itemize}
\begin{align*}
 TJMA_{h} = TJMA_{0} \times (1+\tau)^{n}
\end{align*}
\textbf{$ TJMA_{h}$} le trafic à l’année horizon. \\
\textbf{$TJMA_{0}$ }: le trafic à l’année de référence. \\
\textbf{n} : nombre d’année. \\
\textbf{$\tau$ }: taux d’accroissement du trafic ($\%$).\\
\subsubsection*{Calcul des trafics effectifs : }
C’est le trafic traduit en unités de véhicules particuliers (U.V.P) en fonction de : 
Type de route et de l’environnement . Pour cela on utilise des coefficients d’équivalence pour 
convertir les PL en (U.V.P). \\
Le trafic effectif donné par la relation : \\
\begin{align*}
T_{eff} = [(1 – Z) + P_{z}]\times TJMA_{h}
\end{align*}
$T_{eff}$: trafic effectif à l’horizon en (UVP/J).\\
\textbf{Z :} pourcentage de poids lourds ($\%$). \\
\textbf{P:} coefficient d’équivalence pour le poids lourds, il dépend de la nature de la route (nombres de voies et de l’environnement). \\
D’après les deux Variantes on a : \\

La précipitation = 562 mm  \textbf{Zone II}  (Nord, la chaine Atlas Tellien). \\
La température équivalente est donc : \textbf{20 C}.
\section*{Dimmenesionnement de la structure de chaussée}
\subsection*{Détermination de la portance de sol-support de chaussée}
TPL = trafic total de la direction la plus sollicitée (TJMA) multiplié par le poids lourds sur la voie de droite.
Avec : 
- Porcentage de poids lourds sur la voie de droite : chaussé bidirectionnelle à 2 voies : 50 $ %$
Donc $  TPL = (4724 \times 0,5 \times 0,20) = 472 PL/j/sens.$ \\
D’après le calcul, la classe de trafic lourd nommé TPL4 \\
Donc nous avons un risque de $ 10% $.
\section*{Les caractéristiques géométrique du tracé}



\subsection*{I.26.  Détermination de la portance de sol-support de chaussée :}
Le sol doit être classé selon la valeur de CBR de densité Proctor modifié maximal : 
On a : CBR = 11, la classe du sol se détermine par : Le module :  
 $ E(MPA)=5 \times CBR                                                                   $
 \begin{align*}
 
                        E = 55 MPA     TPL4
 \end{align*} 




 

 

\end{document}
```

Can you please help me finding solution for that.

Comment: We need more information to be able to answer your question.  Please add a brief compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem, giving us something to experiment with.  Also, please state whether you are using pdflatex, xelatex, or lualatex, as the behavior of all of these is different.

Comment: the greek characters are not by default set up in inputenc, you could define tau to be `\tau` but I wouldn't recommend it, the other messages are errors in your document but as you have not shown your code nor the complete error message it is not possible to help.  don't show error messages as images (especially the more or less useless summary of the messages shown by that editor) show the actual errors from the log file and a small complete document that reproduces the error.

Comment: I have added my code in my post, you can now compile it and see where is the problem.

Comment: There does not seem to be any input enc errors in this MWE. But a lot of LaTeX errors. For example, remember that from `%` and the rest of the line is ignored, so `50 $ % $` is really bad as the last `$` is ignored, you want `$50\%$`. There are many of these. and missing `$`. Additionally you are not allowed to have blank lines in `align*`

Comment: Additionally you need a `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as pre warning from french babel, and you should not be using `–` as the minus (this is an en-dahs), use `-` (a hyphen)

Comment: Then it compiles just fine for me. BTW you should remove those images as we do not have access to them and have to use `\usepackage[demo]{graphics}` to get the MWE to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is mostly that you used the percent sign incorrectly. % sign is used for commenting or making a comment that a compiler ignores. You used something like `$10%$`. This basically comments out the other $ sign and makes the inline math environment incomplete. To use percent sign, type `\%` instead of `%`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
République Algérienne Démocratique et Populaire\\
\end{LARGE}
\begin{LARGE}
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieure et de la Recherche Scientifique.\\
 \bigskip 
 \bigskip
\end{LARGE}
\textsc{Ecole National Supérieure Travaux Publics Kouba}\\
\medskip
Cycle d'ingénieur - Deuxième Année.\\
Département des Matériaux et Structure.\\
\bigskip
\begin{Huge}
\underline{\textbf{Etude de projet routier}}\\
\end{Huge}
\bigskip
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width= 14cm , height= 7cm]{../../Documents/Carte Médéa.PNG}  
\end{center}
\bigskip
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{2pt}\\
\bigskip
\begin{LARGE}
\textbf{L'évitement de la Wilaya de Médéa}\\
\end{LARGE}
\bigskip
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
    \underline{\emph{Sous Groupe: 9}}\\
    \textsc{GASMI} Mohamed Wassim.\\
                \textsc{RAHMANI} Mahmoud.\\
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
    \underline{\emph{Responsable de Matière:}} \\
  \textsc{Mr.DERRADJI} \\
  \end{flushright}

\end{minipage}
 \vspace{1in}
\begin{center}
Gharidi, Kouba\\
2020/2021
\end{center}
\end{center}
\newpage
\vspace{2in}
\begin{center}
\huge{\textbf{Remerciement}} \\ [0.75cm]
\textit{Avant tout développement sur cette expérience professionnelle, il est tellement agréable de
commencer ce rapport par des remerciements, à ceux qui m’ont beaucoup appris au
cours de cette sortie, et même à ceux qui ont eu la gentillesse de faire un moment très profitable.}\\
\textit{Aussi, on remercie Mr.DERRADJI qui nous ont formés et accompagnés tout au long de cette expérience d'apprentissage avec beaucoup de patience et de pédagogie.}
\end{center}
\newpage
\section*{Introduction}
L'avant Projet sommaire est entrepris une fois sélectionnée les solutions retenues\\ de la phase 1 (étude préliminaire). Il a pour tache principale de préciser la solution la plus adaptée  à partir d'un plan topographique à l'échelle de 1/5000. Il s'agit de à partir du couloir retenu, de définir le tracé le plus approprié et le plus  économique et de préciser le cadre de dimensionnement(normes d'aménagement) applicable au projet\\
Quelques ripages d'axes pourront etre effectués ainsi que des modifications de ligne rouge (profil en long). Les études de drainage et d'assainissement sont également entreprises dans cette phase. 
\section*{Objectif}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Elaboration du tracé avec le choix définitif des caractéristiques géométriques.
\item Définir le tracé comme une succession d'alignement, de rayons et de raccordements à courbure progressive.
\item déterminer les valeurs des paramètres de dimension du projet, de façon à permettre l'estimation du coût du projet.
\end{enumerate}
\section*{Situation et définition du Projet:}
 Le tronçon routier va permettre de soulager l’agglomération du chef-lieu du flux de véhicules circulant dans les deux sens et qui encombraient la ville. La mise en service du contournement va, à coup sûr, mettre fin au goulot d’étranglement qui a toujours marqué le passage par le carrefour Est, en assurant une meilleure fluidité de la circulation du et vers le centre-ville. La nouvelle voie de contournement va mettre fin au problème de congestion à l’entrée de la ville, causée par les flux de véhicules de gros tonnage qui empruntent la RN1 et, ainsi, faire gagner beaucoup de temps aux usagers de ce tronçon.\\
      Les travaux de réalisation de l’évitement de la ville de Médéa s’inscrivent aussi dans le cadre du renforcement du programme de la réhabilitation du réseau routier mené depuis plusieurs années dans l’objectif d’arriver à une meilleure fluidification de la circulation et une meilleure régulation des véhicules empruntant les principales pénétrantes de la wilaya.le réseau routier existant a nécessité d’importants travaux de réfection et de traitement contre les dégradations causées par l’érosion et par la circulation de véhicules devenue de plus en plus importante du fait de l’augmentation du parc automobile.Le lancement d’un mégaprojet de l'évitement de la wilya de Médéa permettra, à terme, de faciliter la circulation des biens et des services, et donnera un plus grand essor aux échanges entre l'ouest et l'est de la ville.     
     \begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=3cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/TP/Départ-Arrivé.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Points de départ et arrivée}
    &
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/TP/Carte géographique.png} 
    \captionof{figure}{Carte géographique de Wilaya de Médéa}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\section*{Rappel sur les deux variantes retenues}
Selon l'étude préliminaire, on a retenue deux variantes optimales:
\subsection*{Variante 1 :}
La longueur totale la Variante 1 est de 7 Km, elle commence au rond point qui donne accés au quartier de DRAA ESSEMAR qui est considérée comme la porte du coté Est de la ville. Le tracé traverse ensuite des terres agricoles à 1.15 km qui est rectiligne puis il passe sur les montagnes de Ain Arayess pour arriver à la route de Tibhirine. La variante continuera son chemin à partir du nord est de la route de Tibhirine d'environ 1.37 km de longueur et contourner les montagnes et les habitations existantes pour arriver à l'ancienne autoroute du coté Nord ouest de la ville. L'alignement reproduit L'autoroute existante du coté Nord ouest et continue son chemin à 1.58 Km de longueur en traversant les terres agricoles. La variante coupe le rond point existant et continue son chemin en traversant les terres agricoles à 4.48 Km de longueur pour arriver au viaduc de l'autoroute Nord-Sud.
\begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=4cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/debut var1.png}  
\captionof{figure}{Point de départ}
    &
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/fin var 1.png}  
    \captionof{figure}{Point d'arrivée}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[height=8cm , width= 15cm]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/var 1.png} 
   \captionof{figure}{Variante 1}
        \end{center}    
        \subsection*{Variante 3}
        La longueur de la variante 3 est de 14.3 Km qui commence par la route Nationale Numéro 18, en traversant le oued, elle monte sur une terre agricole d'altitude 713 m puis elle traverse une route existante pour rentrer dans les terres d'altitude minimales sur une longueur de 9.17 m qui nous permettre de contourner la zone d'habitation et les propriétés privées et les terres agricoles. Sur cette longueur, elle traverse 2 routes de plus pour arriver à l'autoroute Nord-Sud.
        \begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=4cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/début var 3.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Point de départ}
    &
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/fin var 3.png} 
    \captionof{figure}{Point d'arrivée}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[height=7cm , width= 15cm]{../../Documents/Projet-Médéa/var 3.png} 
  \captionof{figure}{Variante 3} 
  \end{center} 
\section*{Un aperçu sur la norme à utiliser}
\subsection*{Etude de Trafic}
La capacité dépend de :
\begin{itemize}
\item  Des conditions de trafic.
\item  Des conditions météorologiques .
\item Le type d’usagers habitués ou non à l’itinéraire .
\item  Des distances de sécurité (ce qui intègre le temps de réaction des Conducteurs 
variables d’une route à l’autre) .
\item Des caractéristiques géométriques de la section considérée (nombre et largeur des 
voies). 
\subsubsection*{Calcul de TJMA}
La formule qui donne le trafic journalier moyen annuel à l’année horizon est : 
\end{itemize}
\begin{align*}
 TJMA_{h} = TJMA_{0} \times (1+\tau)^{n}
\end{align*}
\textbf{$ TJMA_{h}$} le trafic à l’année horizon. \\
\textbf{$TJMA_{0}$ }: le trafic à l’année de référence. \\
\textbf{n} : nombre d’année. \\
\textbf{$\tau$ }: taux d’accroissement du trafic ($\%$).\\
\subsubsection*{Calcul des trafics effectifs : }
C’est le trafic traduit en unités de véhicules particuliers (U.V.P) en fonction de : 
Type de route et de l’environnement . Pour cela on utilise des coefficients d’équivalence pour 
convertir les PL en (U.V.P). \\
Le trafic effectif donné par la relation : \\
\begin{align*}
T_{eff} = [(1 – Z) + P_{z}]\times TJMA_{h}
\end{align*}
$T_{eff}$: trafic effectif à l’horizon en (UVP/J).\\
\textbf{Z :} pourcentage de poids lourds ($\%$). \\
\textbf{P:} coefficient d’équivalence pour le poids lourds, il dépend de la nature de la route (nombres de voies et de l’environnement). \\
D’après les deux Variantes on a : \\

La précipitation = 562 mm  \textbf{Zone II}  (Nord, la chaine Atlas Tellien). \\
La température équivalente est donc : \textbf{20 C}.
\section*{Dimmenesionnement de la structure de chaussée}
\subsection*{Détermination de la portance de sol-support de chaussée}
TPL = trafic total de la direction la plus sollicitée (TJMA) multiplié par le poids lourds sur la voie de droite.
Avec : 
- Porcentage de poids lourds sur la voie de droite : chaussé bidirectionnelle à 2 voies : 50\%
Donc $  TPL = (4724 \times 0,5 \times 0,20) = 472 PL/j/sens.$ \\
D’après le calcul, la classe de trafic lourd nommé TPL4 \\
Donc nous avons un risque de 10\% .
\section*{Les caractéristiques géométrique du tracé}



\subsection*{I.26.  Détermination de la portance de sol-support de chaussée :}
Le sol doit être classé selon la valeur de CBR de densité Proctor modifié maximal : 
On a : CBR = 11, la classe du sol se détermine par : Le module :  
 
 \begin{align*}
 E(MPA)&=5 \times CBR\\
 E &= 55 MPA     TPL4\\
 \end{align*} 

\end{document}
```